# excel UDF resulting in hyperlink as text

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, hyperlink, udf

All of the UDFs to display hyperlinks (that I have seen) only work where the hyperlink is a URL but they do not work where the hyperlink is another cell in the same workbook. Can anyone help me find a UDF that results in the hyperlink as text where the hyperlink is another cell in the same workbook? Thanks.

Here is a screenshot of the hyperlink, which was created using >Insert > Hyperlink..., and the cell reference that is displayed in the bubble when I hover over the hyperlink cell...

This is the cell reference that I want the UDF to return as text in any other cell.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Could you show an example of a UDF that doesn't work?

Comment: UDFs can't usually be used to change a workbook or worksheet.  They usually take some parameter(s) and process it to return a result,  just like the built in functions like `=SUM(range1, range2....)`.  A Procedure (`Sub`) is built to change things on sheets or in workbooks.  So when you ask about UDF do you mean a `Function` or `Sub`?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code:

```vb
' Add hyperlink to a cess on Sheet2
Sheets("Sheet2").Hyperlinks.Add _
' Hyperlink must follow to a single cell A1 on Sheet1
' To follow another object (multicell range, chart, etc.) specify it
    Anchor:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"), _
' Address must be empty - it is local hyperlink
    Address:="", _
' Specify destination address where hyperlink will be placed
    SubAddress:= "Sheet2!A1", _
' Specify the text of a hyperlink
    TextToDisplay:="HyperLink to A1 on Sheet2"
```